# Using spanSizeLookup in Kotlin to set span size based on ItemViewType in GridLayoutManager

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-gridlayout

I have a a RecyclerView that uses GridLayoutManager to display data, I'm trying to span an item fully if the ItemViewType matches being a title. I know how its done in java, but in Kotlin I cant get the override method that returns the position of the item to determine its type.

```
layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(context, 2);
    layoutManager .setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
        @Override
        public int getSpanSize(int position) {
            switch (adapter.getItemViewType(position)) {
                case 0:
                    return 2;
                default:
                    return 1;
            }
        }
    });
```

Above is the code I need in Java, and couldn't find any documents that explains the spanSizeLookup in Kotlin. Below is what I have so far in Kotlin.

```
binding.lmHomeStatusRecyclerViewList.apply {
            var layout: GridLayoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this.context, 2).apply {
               /*  spanSizeLookup???
                   if (obAdapter.getItemViewType(**position**) == NAME ){
                }*/  
            }
            layoutManager = layout
            this.setHasFixedSize(true)
            obAdapter.list = dataManager.loDataList
            adapter = obAdapter
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

After reading so many vague documentations, I found the solution. Inside the .apply{} add the following:

```
spanSizeLookup = object : GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
                    override fun getSpanSize(position: Int): Int {
                        return when (obAdapter.getItemViewType(position)){
                                    NAME -> 2
                                    else ->  1
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Basically create an object of type GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() then you will be able to reach the override function/method to reach the position of each item in the Grid, and assign a span value based on the itemViewType assigned in the adapter.

Comment: Thank you! It appears SpanSizeLookup is an abstract class, that's why "object" keyword is needed.